# Apache rewriterule with proxyPass and proxyPassReverse

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, httpd.conf, proxypass

I need to use the following Rewrite rule with the proxyPass and proxyPassReverse

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(market|stock|mutual)$ stackoverflow/$1 [L]
```

My virtual host defination is

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/  
</VirtualHost>
```

Where Shall I insert the rewrite rule so that when I hit the URL -- localhost/market, then it will perform an internal rewrite to localhost:8080/stackoverflow/market

Please help

Answer (score 2):

Got it

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/stackoverflow/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/stackoverflow/ 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule  ^(market|stock|mutual)$ stackoverflow/$1 [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you help me understand why placing a `RewriteRule` in a `<Directory>` section has no effect in this case? Is it because the `ProxyPass` takes effect first so the other directives are not applied?

Comment: iX3, you are correct. ProxyPass takes precedence before mod_rewrite and mod_alias.